# R: condense the data in the data matrix?

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
    class1  class2  class3  class4  class5  class6
1   <NA>    PATH    PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>
2   PATH    PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
3   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4   PATH    PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    VUS
5   <NA>    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6   PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>
7   MPATH   VUS VUS PATH    <NA>    <NA>
8   PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
9   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
10  PATH    <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
11  VUS <NA>    <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>
12  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>
13  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
14  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
15  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    VUS
16  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    VUS
17  PATH    <NA>    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
18  PATH    <NA>    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
19  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
20  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
```

This data matrix contains 6 columns, class1 to class6, each row contains PATH, VUS, .., some rows with "NA" in the column of class1 to class6, I want the first several cols should be "non NA" value, for examples: row 1: PATH in class2 and class3 will move to class1 and class2. 
The output should be like this:

```
    class1  class2  class3  class4  class5  class6
1   PATH    PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
2   PATH    PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
3   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4   PATH    PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>
5   PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6   PATH    VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>
7   MPATH   VUS VUS PATH    <NA>    <NA>
8   PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
9   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
10  PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
11  VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
12  VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
13  PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
14  PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
15  VUS VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>
16  VUS VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>
17  PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
18  PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
19  PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
20  PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Row 1 is the same in your sample data and expected output. The only thing that seems to have changed is the order of rows. What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the input and output data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, hence two options.

**Option 1: If you want to move `NA`s to the end of a row *only if they occur in column 1*. A row starting with a non-`NA` will be left unmodified, even if there are `NA`s at other positions.**

We can do the following:

```
# Function to circular shift entries to the left 
lshift <- function(x) {
  c(tail(x, -1), head(x, 1))
}

as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    while (x[1] == "<NA>") x <- lshift(x); x;
})))
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
#1   PATH PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA>
#2   PATH PATH  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3    VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4   PATH PATH  VUS <NA> <NA>  VUS
#5   PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6   PATH  VUS  VUS <NA>  VUS <NA>
#7  MPATH  VUS  VUS PATH <NA> <NA>
#8   PATH  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#9    VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#10  PATH <NA>  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#11   VUS <NA> <NA>  VUS <NA> <NA>
#12   VUS  VUS <NA>  VUS <NA> <NA>
#13  PATH PATH <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
#14  PATH PATH <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
#15   VUS  VUS <NA>  VUS <NA>  VUS
#16   VUS  VUS <NA>  VUS <NA>  VUS
#17  PATH <NA> <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
#18  PATH <NA> <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
#19  PATH PATH <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
#20  PATH PATH <NA> PATH <NA> <NA>
```

---

**Option 2: If you want to move *all* `NA`s to the end of every row.**

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x[x != "<NA>"], x[x == "<NA>"]))))
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
#1   PATH PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA>
#2   PATH PATH  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3    VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4   PATH PATH  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA>
#5   PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6   PATH  VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA>
#7  MPATH  VUS  VUS PATH <NA> <NA>
#8   PATH  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#9    VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#10  PATH  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#11   VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#12   VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA> <NA>
#13  PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA>
#14  PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA>
#15   VUS  VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA>
#16   VUS  VUS  VUS  VUS <NA> <NA>
#17  PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#18  PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#19  PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA>
#20  PATH PATH PATH <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "    class1  class2  class3  class4  class5  class6
1   <NA>    PATH    PATH    PATH    PATH    <NA>
2   PATH    PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
3   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4   PATH    PATH    VUS <NA>    <NA>    VUS
5   <NA>    PATH    PATH    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6   PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>
7   MPATH   VUS VUS PATH    <NA>    <NA>
8   PATH    VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
9   VUS VUS VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
10  PATH    <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
11  VUS <NA>    <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>
12  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    <NA>
13  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
14  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
15  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    VUS
16  VUS VUS <NA>    VUS <NA>    VUS
17  PATH    <NA>    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
18  PATH    <NA>    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
19  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>
20  PATH    PATH    <NA>    PATH    <NA>    <NA>",
header = T, row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `apply` and `order` with `na.last = TRUE`:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(x)x[order(x, na.last = TRUE)]))
```

OR column order needs to be maintained then:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(x){
                  ret <- x[!is.na(x)] 
                  length(ret) <- length(x)
                  ret
                       })

  #      [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5] [,6]
  # 1  "PATH"  "PATH" "PATH" "PATH" NA   NA  
  # 2  "PATH"  "PATH" "VUS"  NA     NA   NA  
  # 3  "VUS"   "VUS"  "VUS"  NA     NA   NA  
  # 4  "PATH"  "PATH" "VUS"  "VUS"  NA   NA  
  # 5  "PATH"  "PATH" NA     NA     NA   NA  
  # 6  "PATH"  "VUS"  "VUS"  "VUS"  NA   NA  
  # 7  "MPATH" "VUS"  "VUS"  "PATH" NA   NA  
  # 8  "PATH"  "VUS"  "VUS"  NA     NA   NA  
  # 9  "VUS"   "VUS"  "VUS"  NA     NA   NA  
  # 10 "PATH"  "VUS"  NA     NA     NA   NA  
  # 11 "VUS"   "VUS"  NA     NA     NA   NA  
  # 12 "VUS"   "VUS"  "VUS"  NA     NA   NA  
  # 13 "PATH"  "PATH" "PATH" NA     NA   NA  
  # 14 "PATH"  "PATH" "PATH" NA     NA   NA  
  # 15 "VUS"   "VUS"  "VUS"  "VUS"  NA   NA  
  # 16 "VUS"   "VUS"  "VUS"  "VUS"  NA   NA  
  # 17 "PATH"  "PATH" NA     NA     NA   NA  
  # 18 "PATH"  "PATH" NA     NA     NA   NA  
  # 19 "PATH"  "PATH" "PATH" NA     NA   NA  
  # 20 "PATH"  "PATH" "PATH" NA     NA   NA
```